# How to Configure Monolog to Email Errors With symfony/mailer

Tags: symfony, mailgun, monolog

In my Symfony 4.3 project I use symfony/mailer with symfony/mailgun-mailer to send emails via [mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com). I want to receive emails about errors, so I use monolog, but in monolog [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/monolog_email.html) I can't find how to send emails via symfony/mailer. Can anyone help me to configure monolog to receive emails about errors via mailgun and if it is possible to add specific tag to that emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the (4.3 and 5.0) monolog docs it's currently not possible to use the new symfony mailer for sending error emails:
https://symfony.com/doc/4.3/logging/monolog_email.html

> This feature is not compatible yet with the new Symfony mailer, so it requires using SwiftMailer.

But, there is an open pull request for monolog bridge that would fix it, maybe its worth watching
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/33456

Comment: Thank you, when I wrote this question there was no caution in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. I just wanted to give pointers for the next one looking for a solution, including my future self :)